# How To Map An Array [Swift]

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array named `bonusCardsTest` of type [BonusCard] that is conformed to Identifiable that has an id and an url property of type String.

```
var bonusCardsTest: [BonusCard] = []

struct BonusCard: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var url: String
}
```

I also have an array named `getBonusURLsArray` of type [String] that contains urls.

What I want is to assign each element of `getBonusURLsArray` to the url property of `bonusCardsTest`.
For example, if `getBonusURLsArray` has two elements - "https://test1.com", "https://test2.com", I want the BonusCard array to look like this:

```
var bonusCardsTest: [BonusCard] = [
BonusCard(url: "https:test1.com"),
BonusCard(url: "https:test2.com"),
]
```

How do I do that?

Comment: `map()` would be the higher level method, else use a basic `for loop`.

Comment: Your title asks about "two arrays", but your question only asks about one. Is that a typo? If not, please clarify your question.

Comment: @Alexander there are two arrays in the question: `bonusCardsTest` and `getBonusURLsArray`

Comment: @Gleb One is just a result of a computation over the other. The two aren't "mapped" together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Larme says, you could map your array of URLs to `BonusCard`s:

```
let bonusCards = getBonusURLsArray.map { BonusCard(url: $0) }
```